# Struts action not triigers when using jCription with struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I am try to encript the user name password in a struts2 project using jCription. i have added a action class and added the key generation code s this article mentioned.

[article](http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/javascript-rsa-encryption-and-java-decryption/)

Below is what the action do inside the execute method, (i have returned null after below code)

```
    JCryptionUtil jCryptionUtil = new JCryptionUtil();

    KeyPair keys = null;
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("keys") == null) {
        keys = jCryptionUtil.generateKeypair(512);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("keys", keys);
    }

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    String e = JCryptionUtil.getPublicKeyExponent(keys);
    String n = JCryptionUtil.getPublicKeyModulus(keys);
    String md = String.valueOf(JCryptionUtil.getMaxDigits(512));

    output.append("{\"e\":\"");
    output.append(e);
    output.append("\",\"n\":\"");
    output.append(n);
    output.append("\",\"maxdigits\":\"");
    output.append(md);
    output.append("\"}");

    output.toString();
    response.getOutputStream().print(
            output.toString().replaceAll("\r", "").replaceAll("\n", "")
                    .trim());
```

I have map the struts action in the struts.xml but I havent add a result tag because this action triggers by a ajax request as below which will use just to add the keys to the session.

```
function getKeys() {
    $.jCryption.getKeys("encryptionAction?generateKeypair=true", function(
            receivedKeys) {
        keys = receivedKeys;
    });
}
```

The problem is above request wont trigger the action class?
What i am missing here? is there any specific additional code i need to put in the struts.xml to specify about the result is json object/

Comment: Of course you need to specify that result is json if you want it to be json.

Comment: You need to include the action configuration. You'd need to set the response type if you insist on duplicating framework functionality by writing directly to the response. What's the spurious `output.toString()` for? It's just throwing away the result. If it's not even hitting the action, it's a config/URL/etc. problem. Once you fix that, fix the rest.

Comment: Also include the jsp, without it it's imaginable that javascript framework is used.

Comment: Thanks Dave. i specified the action name path and type in struts config with out a result tag.I guess that would be enough in struts configaration file right? Also can you please explain what you mean by "You'd need to set the response type if you insist on duplicating framework functionality by writing directly to the response"? You mean add the <result type="json" /> in action tag?

Comment: Also in here in action class i already construct a json object and write it to the response object do i need to add extra json jars and extend json-default etc